# 2 unresolved externals

Tags: php, c, windows, visual-studio-2008, php-extension

I'm trying to compile a hello world php extension project and I'm getting 2 errors about unresolved externals. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, can someone tell me what might be the problem?

project file [here](http://blog.slickedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/customext.zip) and you can also see the code in [this post](http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/)

```
1>CustomExt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___estrndup referenced in function "void __cdecl zif_DoubleUp(int,struct _zval_struct *,struct _zval_struct * *,struct _zval_struct *,int,void * * *)" (?zif_DoubleUp@@YAXHPAU_zval_struct@@PAPAU1@0HPAPAPAX@Z)
1>CustomExt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__zend_parse_parameters referenced in function "void __cdecl zif_DoubleUp(int,struct _zval_struct *,struct _zval_struct * *,struct _zval_struct *,int,void * * *)" (?zif_DoubleUp@@YAXHPAU_zval_struct@@PAPAU1@0HPAPAPAX@Z)
```

Comment: That means some header file is missing.

Comment: I'd more tend to missing librarie(s)/object file(s). This error does occurr during the link phase, doesn't it?

Comment: Of course. Maybe this php5ts.lib is not there?

Comment: @Jitamaro: As I'm not PHP guy if have no idea where `estrndup()` and `zend_parse_parameters()` are located.

Comment: I've had the same problem in my project but I could solve it.  What is a .lib file in Windows anyway?

Comment: @jitamaro A lib file is library, a collection of objects.

Comment: You must link against php5.lib or php5ts.lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determine in which *.lib or .o file  `estrndup()` and `zend_parse_parameters()` are located and tell the linker to add such file(s) during the link phase.